# DESC query is not showing right results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the best player on a page and using this php code to get the result

```
<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';
//query all records from the database
$query = "select cwins, close, name, id
from cseason ORDER BY cwins DESC LIMIT 1";
//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
//get number of rows returned
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
//this will link us to our add.php to create new record
if( $num_results > 0){
//loop to show each records
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
//extract row
//this will make $row['firstname'] to
//just $firstname only
extract($row);
//creating new table row per record
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
echo '<td align="center">';
if (($cwins + $close) != 0) $rate = (($cwins / ($cwins + $close)) * 100);
else $rate = 0;
if ($rate > 70) {
echo "<span class='badge badge-success'>";
print round ($rate);
} elseif ($rate < 40) {
echo "<span class='badge badge-important'>";
print round ($rate);
}
else {
echo "<span class='badge badge-warning'>";
print round ($rate);
}
echo '</span>';
echo '</td>';
}
echo "</tr></table>";//end table
}else{
//if database table is empty
echo "No records found.";
}
//disconnect from database
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Here is the data in cseason

```
[     id    ] [   name    ] [   cwins     ] [   close   ]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - -
[     1    ]  [   rick    ] [      11     ] [       1   ]
[     2    ]  [   dave    ] [      6      ] [       6   ]
[     3    ]  [   neil    ] [      7      ] [       5   ]
[     4    ]  [   simon   ] [      3      ] [       9   ]
```

It currently displays Neil which is wrong.

I ran the code directly in phpmyadmin and it comes up with the same answer.

Where have I gone or what have I over seen?

---

Ok i have gone into phpMYadmin to investigate there and found when i try to reorder the column 'cwins' the row neil still goes to the top...

Comment: What datatype is the `cwins` column? I bet it is a varchar.

Comment: Are the cwins `7` and `3` just displayed wrong here, or are they really padded with spaces? If they are, then you're getting a perfectly NORMAL string sorting output. Change the field to an int and it will "just work".

Comment: sorry thats my bad table rendering in the op, i have noticed something else with i will post in my OP

Comment: Also best practice when inserting the string use trim() so it gets rid of the spaces, only if you want it to stay a varchar.

Comment: @JohnConde i think your right if so what can i do about it?

Comment: It should be as simple as changing the field to be of an integer type. That shouldn't affect your data and will solve your sorting issue.

Comment: Yep thats done the job thx everyone :)

Comment: @JohnConde I have just tested this myself, created database etc. I do get the correct result i.e. rick. Can you explain why I would get the right value and the op does not. Presumably is there some whitespace in the field or something?

Comment: hack fix: select cwins, close, name, id from cseason ORDER BY cwins+0 DESC LIMIT 1